# Delegates: pass data without segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have two simple classes that pass information with delegates like so:

```
protocol VCBDelegate: class {
func buttonDidPress() }

class ViewControllerBefore: UIViewController {

weak var delegate: VCBDelegate?
let vc = ViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = vc
}

@IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.buttonDidPress()
} }

class ViewController: UIViewController, VCBDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Everything works fine and the function buttonDidPress is triggered.
But my problem is that if I want to reload a collection view, then the collection view is nil because of the way I instantiate the ViewController object in the ViewControllerBefore class.
Keep in mind that I cannot assign the delegate in a segue, because the two view controllers are not connected.

See here below the buttonDidPress function:

```
func buttonDidPress() {         
  dataCell.infoCell.insert(addDataCell.getBuyCell(), at: 0)
  self.cvHome.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are connected, because they are both in the same view hierarchy (or at least they should be). `let vc = ViewController()` is certainly the wrong way to do things. How are the two controllers related to each other, what is their job, are they children of the same parent, is one the parent / container of the other?

Comment: The one above is a simplified version of my app, but basically there is a Tab Bar Controller --> Navigation Controller --> View Controller.

Comment: Then from Tab Bar Controller --> Another View Controller --> Instantiates with identifier the View Controller Before

Answer (score 1):

I like to store the data inside of a `dataSource` for these circumstances. I can access the data from anywhere in the app once it's been set.

```
class PageDataSource {

    var theData : [Any]?

    static let sharedInstance = PageDataSource()
    private init() {}
}
```

To make sure I pass the info through the `delegate` and I store it to the `dataSource` I do this:

```
func doDelegate() {
    PageDataSource.sharedInstance.theData = whatever
    passData(whatever)
    dismiss(true, nil)
}
```

Then I make sure that the `tableView` or `collectionView` is getting the information it needs from `PageDataSource.sharedInstance.theData` for example:

```
// MARK: CollectionView DataSource
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if PageDataSource.sharedInstance.theData.count >= 1 {
            return PageDataSource.sharedInstance.theData.count
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: I see your point, but I will have to re-structure my entire app. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I can give a more tailored solution if you can give more detail in your question. What data is being passed by the delegate? What do you do with it when it gets passed? How are you handling the table view?

Comment: Actually, no data is passed, I only want to confirm that a button was pressed. Once that button is pressed, in the ViewController I do some changes and reload the table view. I used to do it with a simple NSNotification, but it was creating issues, like being called multiple times.

Comment: declare a `Bool` in the Vc with the `tableView` and assign it the value `true` with the delegate. Then when you have the `tableView` load the data load it one way on `false` and another on `true`

Comment: I have already tried this solution but unfortunately the reload method is not taking the updated data that were modified through the delegate method

Comment: Would you update your question to display your issue then? We can’t help without being able to see the code you’re actually having problems with.

Comment: Thank you so much!!