# Setting textfield value into a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield which takes users input and this input is printed in the console. I now want to be able to pass another string from a different viewcontroller so what I did was to create a variable and set the text from the text field into it and also when I am click on a button, automatically fill up the textfield with a constant value but when I print, the console prints `nil` everytime. below is what i have tried

`var topText: String!`

`self.topText = self.topTextField.text!`

then I printed this in my didChangeValue function

`print("TOPUP TET \(self.topText)")` which returns `nil` everytime despite having a text there.

Comment: `topUpText` is not the same as `self.topText`?

Comment: "_then I printed this in my didChangeValue function_" Where are these functions? Show the rest of your code.

Comment: Still you ques is unclear to users, you must add some more code and explain in better way then.

Comment: not related, but of force unwrap, you should use 'if let'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code compiles then you have two properties in your class `topUpText` and `topText` and you assign to one and print the other.

If this is about passing values between view controllers maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090909/swift-3-passing-data-between-a-view-controller-and-after-that-to-another-2) might help solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using and referring the same variable for getting and setting value,

```
var topUpText: String!

self.topUpText = self.topTextField.text!

print("TOPUP TET \(self.topUpText)")
```