# How to access ViewController's class functions from another class?

Tags: swift, segue, mlmodel

I have this function in the ViewController class:

```
func detect(image: CIImage) {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model)
        else {
            fatalError("Loading CoreML Model Failed.")
    }

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) {
        (request, error) in
        guard let result = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]
            else {
                fatalError("Model failed to process image.")
        }
        print(result.first?.identifier as Any)
        self.imageLabel.text = result.first?.identifier
    }

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)
    do {
        try handler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the result.first?.identifier to do something like this in another class called SecondViewController:

```
if(result.first?.identifier == "flowers") {
    self.infoLabel.text = "info about flowers"
}
```

but I don't know how to access the function in the other class. I just started coding in Swift.

Comment: post a notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 - Passing data between a View Controller and after that to another 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090909/swift-3-passing-data-between-a-view-controller-and-after-that-to-another-2)

Comment: That answer hasn't really helped me. @dengApro

Comment: Could you give me more info on how to do that depending on the result of the ML Model? Thanks. @LeoDabus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329316/2303865

Comment: Thank you @LeoDabus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a link](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/) that helped me to solve this problem I was encountering, I'm going to share it here if anyone ever needs it in the future.