# UICollectionView numberOfItemsInSection not being called on reloadData() - Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have two view controllers – SecondTestViewController and SecondContentViewController. SecondContentViewController is a ***floating panel*** inside SecondTestViewController. SecondTestViewController has a UITableView and SecondContentViewController has a UICollectionView.

*SecondContentViewController:*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout())
        guard let myCollectionView = myCollectionView else {
            return
        }
        myCollectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
        myCollectionView.isSpringLoaded = true
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            myCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            myCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            myCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
    
    private func collectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cellWidthHeightConstant: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.2
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50,
                                           left: 10,
                                           bottom: 0,
                                           right: 10)
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidthHeightConstant, height: cellWidthHeightConstant)
        
        return layout
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        return contentData.count
        print("numberOfItemsInSection activated")
        print("numberOfItemsInSection = \(reviewDataController?.tableViewReviewData.count ?? 100)")
        return reviewDataController?.tableViewReviewData.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("cellForItemAt activated")
        let cell = myCollectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
//        cell.data = self.contentData[indexPath.item]
        cell.data = self.reviewDataController.tableViewReviewData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 5, height: collectionView.frame.height / 10)
    }
    
    
    func updateTheCollectionView() {
        print("updateCollectionView activated")
        print("reviewData count = \(reviewDataController.tableViewReviewData.count)")
        myCollectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

When a cell in SecondTestViewController's tableView is tapped, it takes a photo, passes the data, and then calls SecondContentViewController's updateTheCollectionView() function.

*This function is called in SecondTestViewController after a photo has been taken and various other tasks completed (like updating the variable, etc.).*

```
func passDataToContentVC() {
        let contentVC = SecondContentViewController()
        contentVC.reviewDataController = self.reviewDataController
        contentVC.updateTheCollectionView()
    }
```

As you can see, reloadData is supposed to be called inside this function. It should now update the view with the new photo. For some reason, it's like reloadData is never called because neither numberOfItemsInSection nor cellForItemsAt are being activated a second time.

What is going wrong? The print statements show that the data is being passed (they show an updated quantity after a photo has been taken). The view simply is not updating with the new data because the two collectionView functions are not being called.

***Edit:***
Here is the floating panel code.

```
fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.delegate = self
        guard let contentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "fpc_secondContent") as? SecondContentViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        fpc.isRemovalInteractionEnabled = false
        fpc.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
```

It's essentially inside of viewDidLoad for the SecondTestViewController.

For more information on how it works: [Visit this github](https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel)

As far as the didSelectRowAt function goes, it's too much code to show here. reviewDataController is dependency injection made up of an array of a struct. Essentially all that happens is when a cell is tapped, it pulls up the camera and allows the user to take a photo, then it stores the photo in the array inside of reviewDataController along with some other properties in the struct that the array is made of. The important part is that it's supposed to pass this data to the floating panel which then updates the collectionView showing the photo that was just taken.

Comment: where you add SecondContentViewController to SecondTestViewController , please add code

Comment: `let contentVC = SecondContentViewController()` you are creating a new instance. This is a different one.

Comment: Can you show your `didSelectItemAt` implementation?

Comment: I added some more of the code.

Comment: @ChristianW it seems you have started using delegates (`fpc.delegate = self`). What are you doing with that currently?

Comment: I haven't done anything with the fpc.delegate apart from what I show in that tiny bit of code. I don't understand how to do anything further with it. Can you show me an example of how I could pass SecondTestViewController's reviewDataController via this delegate to SecondContentViewController? I learn by implementing and getting hands on, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChristianW Let me get this straight. `SecondContentViewController` is a floating panel inside `SecondTestViewController`. You are trying to pass data from `SecondTestViewController` to `SecondContentViewController`.

Comment: No, I'm trying to pass data from SecondTestViewController to SecondContentViewController. SecondContentViewController is a floating panel inside of SecondTestViewController – kind of like Maps is set up, or Stocks. When I take a photo in SecondTestViewController, I need to pass that data (reviewDataController) to SecondContentViewController (the floating panel) so that it can be displayed in SecondContentViewController's UICollectionView (inside the floating panel). Also, how would I call the collectionView's reloadData() after passing the data to SecondContentViewController via delegate? Thnx

Comment: @ChristianW I deleted my first comment right after I realized that. Is my comment above correct?

Comment: @aheze Yes, your updated comment is correct.

Comment: I was able to pass data to the floating panel view controller (from SecondTestViewController to SecondContentViewController) by following this person's answer: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978261/13062902) It utilizes passing data via a dataSource. It does not require a segue and the data is available anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing data from `SecondTestViewController` to `SecondContentViewController`, which is forwards and not backwards, you don't need delegates or anything.

Instead, all you need to do is retain a reference to `SecondContentViewController`. Try something like this:

```
class SecondTestViewController {
    var secondContentReference: SecondContentViewController? /// keep a reference here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.delegate = self
        guard let contentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "fpc_secondContent") as? SecondContentViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        fpc.isRemovalInteractionEnabled = false
        fpc.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)

        self.secondContentReference = contentVC /// assign contentVC to the reference
    }
}
```

`secondContentReference` keeps a reference to your `SecondContentViewController`. Now, inside `passDataToContentVC`, use that instead of making a new instance with `let contentVC = SecondContentViewController()`.

Replace

```
func passDataToContentVC() {
    let contentVC = SecondContentViewController()
    contentVC.reviewDataController = self.reviewDataController
    contentVC.updateTheCollectionView()
}
```

... with

```
func passDataToContentVC() {
    secondContentReference?.reviewDataController = self.reviewDataController
    secondContentReference?.updateTheCollectionView()
}
```

Comment: It says the two following errors: "Value of type 'FloatingPanelController?' has no member 'reviewDataController'" and "Value of type 'FloatingPanelController' has no member 'updateTheCollectionView'."

Comment: @ChristianW I meant to say `SecondContentViewController` instead of `FloatingPanelController`. See my edit

Comment: Alright thanks for updating that information!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

```
let contentVC = SecondContentViewController() // this is a new instance
contentVC.reviewDataController = self.reviewDataController
contentVC.updateTheCollectionView()
```

You create an instance and add it to `SecondTestViewController`  but `passDataToContentVC`  has another new one , hence no updates for the shown one

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. How would you recommend passing the data to the floating view controller then, seeing as how there are no segues between the two? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @ChristianW you can use delegates, closures, a shared singleton class... lots of ways... I prefer closures though

Comment: Please provide a quick example if you don't mind. There's very little information out there that involve handling floating panels.

Comment: Where in code you add that floating panel please update question of the snippet and where you wrote it's code for a help

Comment: I already did. Side note: I found this tutorial for passing data via delegates, but it utilizes segues to set the delegates. I don't think this will work because I don't ever segue between SecondTestViewController and SecondContentViewController. Thoughts? https://medium.com/@astitv96/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-4-beginners-e32828862d3f